# Using proxypass with plesk, show admin session ip

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, plesk

I've setup a subdomain for use with plesk so I don't have to type out the port all the time.

Here is my `HTTP` configuration:

```
SSLProxyEngine Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule $ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Here is my `HTTPS` configuration:

```
SSLProxyEngine On
AllowEncodedSlashes On

<Location />
    ProxyPass https://localhost:8443/
    ProxyPassReverse https://localhost:8443/
</Location>
```

Here is my `nginx` configuration (doesn't do anything I need, just tried it):

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

It shows the IP as 127.0.0.1, how can I get my real IP to show up when behind ProxyPass?

Comment: That is the effect of using a proxy... As the X-forwarded-for Header has been set, your provide Plesk with the original IP-address but displaying that probably requires changes to your control panel, which may or may not be supported by the vendor.

Comment: Last I checked, Plex wasn’t too proxy-happy. Other than that, HBruijn is right, of course: The (server) application has to support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you merely needed to modify a fastcgi parameter, and since plesk runs it's own instance it won't interfere with any other services.

Add the following line to `/etc/sw-cp-server/fastcgi_params`:

```
fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_real_ip;
```

Or just run this command with appropriate privleges:

```
echo 'fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_real_ip;' > /etc/sw-cp-server/fastcgi_params
```

Then restart the service:

```
/etc/init.d/sw-cp-server restart
```